# Как удалить последное сообщение бота

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

У меня есть бот который выводит файл .pdf и если пользователь находиться в текущей сессии запускается таймер который через 8 секунд выводит новое сообщение. Как удалить сообщение с файлом .pdf после вывода нового сообщения? У меня выдает ошибку message to delete not found.

```
@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda call: call.data == 'cake')
def cake(call: types.CallbackQuery):
    global flag
    flag = True
    N = 1
    bot.delete_message(message_id=call.message.message_id, chat_id=call.message.chat.id)
    global information
    information.append('Cake')
    markup = types.InlineKeyboardMarkup(row_width=1).add(types.InlineKeyboardButton('Order', callback_data='order'),
                                                         types.InlineKeyboardButton('Main menu', callback_data='main_back'))
    bot.send_document(call.message.chat.id, open(r'file.pdf', 'rb'), caption='Catalog', reply_markup=markup)
    while N:
        sleep(3)
        if not flag:
            break
        sleep(5)
        bot.delete_message(message_id=call.message.message_id, chat_id=call.message.chat.id)
        bot.send_message(call.message.chat.id, 'Have you already chosen which cake you want to order?', reply_markup=markup)
        N -= 1
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
delfile = bot.send_document...

bot.delete_message(message_id=document.message_id, chat_id=call.message.chat.id)
```